# How to assign value to RadioButton

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular2-forms

Here i have data Gener Like 1 or 2 When i click on Link Button its show 1 or 2 in Textbox Perfectly but when i changed its into Radio buttons why its not Showing..

**TextBox Code**

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Gen" formControlName="Gen" value="1" name="Gen" />
```

**RadioButton**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate [formGroup]="EmployeeForm">

 <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':(EmployeeForm.get('Gen').touched||
                 EmployeeForm.get('Gen').dirty)&&
                 !EmployeeForm.get('Gen').valid}">
     <input  type="radio" [(ngModel)]="Gen" formControlName="Gen" value="1" name="Gen" />Male
                    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="Gen" formControlName="Gen" value="2" name="Gen" />FE-Mal
```

Comment: `ngModel` is used for template-driven forms. `formControlName` is for reactive forms. You should not combine the two in one element.

Comment: Hai Deborahk i copied This code from your Angulr2 tutoriall From plural site Coud u plz give any hint

Comment: I added an answer below since I can't format text in the comment.

Comment: @DEborahk could u plz reffer my Updated Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to approach this.

### **TEMPLATE-DRIVEN APPRAOCH**

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">


  <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    <label>
        <input 
            type="radio" 
            name="gender" 
            id="{{gender}}" 
            [value]="gender" 
            ngModel 
            required>
        {{ gender }} 
    </label>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    genders = ['male', 'female']; 
}
```

---

### **REACTIVE APPROACH**

**app.component.html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
    <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          formControlName="gender"
          [value]="gender">{{ gender }}
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  genders = ['male', 'female'];
  signupForm: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'username': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    console.log(this.signupForm)
  }
}
```

Comment: Tq soo much  its Really Nice ans

Answer (score 3):

Try without formControlName:

```
 <input  type="radio" [(ngModel)]="Gen" value="1" name="Gen" />Male
 <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="Gen" value="2" name="Gen" />FE-Mal

 {{Gen}}
```

check this to understand why: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10314#issuecomment-242218563

Comment: Im  Getting This Error Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("ontrolName="Gen" value="1" name="Gen" />Male-->

Comment: make sure you are importing 
FormsModule in app.module.ts file, and make sure to add it into the imports[] array.

Answer (score 1):

The code from my "Angular Reactive Forms" course shows it two ways:

Using Reactive Forms:

```
  <div class="form-group" >
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Send Notifications</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
              <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" 
                         value="email" 
                         formControlName = "notification">Email
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" 
                         value="text" 
                         formControlName = "notification">Text
              </label>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Notice that there are no `ngModel` two-way bindings here.

Using Template-driven forms:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Address Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="home"
                        [(ngModel)]="customer.addressType"
                        name="addressType">Home
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="work"
                        [(ngModel)]="customer.addressType"
                        name="addressType">Work
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="other"
                        [(ngModel)]="customer.addressType"
                        name="addressType">Other
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that there is no `formControlName` used here.

Comment: Thank u Soo much For ur Greate Ans